# Almacenar consulta en array

Tags: php, mysql, array

Muy buenas a todos. Necesito solventar algo que no puedo dar con ello. 
Tengo una consulta mysql donde extraigo los totales de ingresos por cada mes del año 2018.

```
$sql_g=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT MONTH(fecha_factura) AS mes, SUM(total_venta) AS total_mes 
FROM facturas,clientes 
WHERE facturas.id_cliente=clientes.id_cliente AND estado_factura=2 AND YEAR(fecha_factura) = 2018 
GROUP BY MONTH(fecha_factura)");
```

Luego ejecuto un While para almacenar los datos en un array donde [0] será "Enero", y así consecutivamente.

```
while ($row_g = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_g)) {

 $meses[] = $row_g['total_mes'];
}
```

e

En mi caso únicamente tengo ingresos los meses de Abril y Marzo. Por lo que me devuelve: Array ( [0] => 513 [1] => 22.8 ) Que es correcto, en Abril son 513 y en Marzo 22.8.

La cuestión es ¿Cómo podría hacer que los meses que no hay ingresos se almacenaran en el array con la cantidad de “0”? Soy consciente que la consulta únicamente devolverá los valores de los meses en los que ha habido ingresos, pero ¿hay alguna forma de crear un array con la estructura de los 12 meses y si no hay ingresos colocar el "0"?

Necesito esto para colocarlo en una gráfica.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Mira [ask] <- ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] <- ACA para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Genera el array de 0, al principio y despues agrega los meses que ya tienes a las posiciones correspondientes.

Podemos generar un array vacío mediante un `for`, ejemplo:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 12; $i++) {
    $meses[] = 0;
}
```

O también podemos generar un array vacío mediante `array_fill`, ejemplo

```
$meses = array_fill(0, 12, null);
```

Y luego, agregamos solo los meses que sabemos que existen:

```
while ($row_g = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_g)) {
    $meses[$row_g['mes']-1] = $row_g['total_mes'];
}
```

Le resto 1 al mes, porque el array esta indexado en 0.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!
Estaba probando con el for, pero realmente me estaba complicando la vida. Gracias!

Comment: Una cosa más, ahora el array me devuelve del 0 al 12 con lo que hay 13 valores. ¿Cómo puedo eliminar el último?

Comment: Ya lo he resuelto con unset()

Comment: Ahh es qie la condicion de corte deberia ser $i < 12. Ahora lo edito.

Comment: @gbianchi Otra opción más elegante para generar el Array de inicio, podría ser: `$meses = array_fill(0, 12, null);` Te dejo mis puntos. saludos.

Comment: @Xerif si te parece que amerita otra respuesta, agregala! si no, edita esta respuesta sin miedo.

Comment: @gbianchi Me tomo la liberta de editar tu respuesta con tu permiso, espero sea de tu agrado. Un saludo.